# Macro for Reapply Filter on Excel 2016

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a Mac and am running Excel 2016. I have an Excel sheet which is auto-filtered by date.

Until recently, I had a macro saved which allowed me to press Command+Option+n and it would reapply the filter without my having to go *Home*->*Sort&Filter*->*Reapply Filter*.

For some reason, the most recent Office updates deleted the macro and I can't seem to find it again.

I have tried recording a macro, but when I run it, it says: `Runtime Error 1004`.

The macro itself reads as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+n
'
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "()"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me how to get this to work? I update the sheet almost constantly, so having a shortcut to refresh the filters made my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Sub ReapplyFilter()
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I try this, prompt me Object variable or With block variable not set, Run-time error!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out I was trying to re-apply the filter on a sheet that didn't have one. Here's the code that worked:

```
    If Not (ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print "Reapplying autofilter for " & ws.Name
        ws.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End If
```